# Where does Mutt save attachment?

Tags: mutt

I use `v` to open attachment list and select an item and hit `s` to save it.

Q1. Now where does Mutt save the attachment?

Q2. How to define a directory where I want to save attachments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, `mutt` saves attachments to whatever the current directory was when you started `mutt`.

If you want to save to a particular directory, `cd` to that directory before starting `mutt`:

```
cd mypreferreddirectory
mutt
```

`mutt` also allows you to define many powerful macros.  To define a macro "W" for saving to a particular directory, put the following in your `~/.muttrc` file:

```
macro attach W <save-entry><kill-line>/home/gawron/attachments/
```

For more on this, see [the mutt FAQ](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Attachment).

Comment: If you use `<bol>` ("beginning of line") instead of `<kill-line>`, you can insert the path before the attachment name, instead of deleting the attachment name every time. Then add `<eol>` to set the cursor at the end of the line for easy editing of the attachment name. For example: `macro attach W "<save-entry><bol>~/Desktop/<eol>" "Save to desktop"`

Comment: If, like me, you want to bind a key to launching a terminal instance + opening mutt, do something like this (for urxvt): `urxvt -cd "your-preferred-directory" -e mutt`. Other terminal emulators work similarly.

Answer (score 4):

After you hit `s` and before you hit `Enter`, mutt proposes a default file name (which is the original name of the attachment). At this point, you can provide mutt with a new directory (and with a different file name).

So if mutt proposes `attach.ment`, just fill in the path you need the file saved to, `~/your/desired/folder/attach.ment` and hit `Enter`.

If you want to save attachments always in the same folder, John1024 describes how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no config option (AFAIK) but here's a simple work around.

The following alias will save your files into an "attachments" folder in your home directory:

alias mutt='cd $HOME/attachments;/usr/bin/mutt;cd -'

Add it to your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

Answer (score -1):

[This page](http://www.pantz.org/software/mutt/muttconfigfiles.html) suggest that procmail determines where the attachments are saved. In that case, check the file `.procmailrc` in your home directory. It should have a line like `SAVE =$MAILDIR/save` which specified where attachments are saved, likely defaulting to your mail directory. It should also have a line like `MAILDIR =$HOME/Mail` which will identify your mail directory.

In your case, it might be `/home/shinokada/mail/save/`.

Naturally, to specify where attachments are saved, just change the `SAVE` variable.

Comment: I don't have .pocmailrc.

Comment: Do you mean `.procmailrc`? If so, then I’m afraid I cannot find the location. There are a small handful of pages that refer to attachments and Mutt, but there is no information about where it is saved (it’s not even in the man-pages). You could try selecting a unique filename when you save one then doing a search for it. If you find the location, then you could try to grep for a file that contains that path.